# How important are GRE Quant scores for a PhD applicant for B-schools?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, gre, business-school

I will be applying for a PhD in Management and Business in non-Math / economics related topics. I have been out of touch with calculus for a few decades and while I *am* studying hard, I am not sure that I will reach the top percentile in GRE in quantitative papers.

My question is: How important are GRE quant scores to the Academic committee of Businesses school PhDs? Esp. the top 20 schools in USA / Canada?

What if I have reasonably good work experience (25 years) across the world (Asia - Far East and London - does this make any difference?)?

Comment: Are you talking about the GRE math **subject area** test or the GRE general quant test? Given what you said about your intended graduate program, I would assume you are NOT taking the GRE math subject area test. However, you talk about calculus, which is well beyond the scope of the GRE general quant test, which usually does not extend much beyond one year of school algebra and one year of school geometry (meaning it even excludes, I believe, many precalculus topics such as trigonometry, conics, logarithms, complex numbers, etc., to say nothing of calculus).

Comment: Look up the schools on Grad Cafe and see what the reported GRE scores are.

Comment: @ Hobbes - Thanks a lot, I was not aware of Gradcafe.

Comment: @ Dave: Thanks a lot. Yes - that clarifies my question. I am only taking the GRE quant test (and of course the qual / verbal etc). Do forgive my ignorance as its been a good two decades plus since me or any of one near me gave a semblance of a GRE. its fun to be a student again, :)

Comment: Incidentally, depending on your background (what math you studied in high school and early college) and your exposure to math since then, you may (or may not) have MORE to "relearn" regarding the GRE quant topics than if it covered topics up through elementary calculus, such as mixture problems, distance equals rate*time problems, "simultaneously working together at their own individual constant rates" problems, geometry problems involving properties of circles and secants and such, percent increase and percent decrease, all sorts of data and table interpretation problems, etc.